# Run script in sleep mode

Tags: suspend, ubuntu-mate

I thought scripts in /lib/systemd/system-sleep/ were run when computer resumes from a sleep state.
(Pushing the sleep button on my computer.)
[image]

Everything works except the cvlc line.

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ "${1}" == "pre" ]; then
  # Do the thing you want before suspend here, e.g.:
  echo "we are suspending at $(date)..." > /tmp/systemd_suspend_test
  cvlc --play-and-exit /usr/share/sounds/My_Sounds/Short_doorbell.wav
elif [ "${1}" == "post" ]; then
  # Do the thing you want after resume here, e.g.:
  echo "...and we are back from $(date)" >> /tmp/systemd_suspend_test
  cvlc --play-and-exit /usr/share/sounds/My_Sounds/Short_doorbell.wav
fi
```

I think I found a clue in my journal.

```
Sep 10 06:36:12 7 systemd-sleep[8316]: VLC is not supposed to be run as root. Sorry.
Sep 10 06:36:12 7 systemd-sleep[8316]: If you need to use real-time priorities and/or privileged TCP ports
Sep 10 06:36:12 7 systemd-sleep[8316]: you can use /usr/bin/vlc-wrapper (make sure it is Set-UID root and
```

Comment: Do you have `cvlc` *(`sudo apt install vlc` ?)* available through `$PATH` as this script runs? Is the wav file also accessible?

Comment: @Hannu Yes, cvlc is installed and in the path. And the wav file is also accessible as it is hard coded in. I had forgotten to add the exe bit. When I did, the script works except for the cvlc line.

Comment: +1 on your clue above.

Comment: @Hannu Thanks. I have decided that scripts in /lib/systemd/system-sleep/ are very limited as to what they can do.

Comment: Nah, they run under special circumstances, so need to be adjusted for that.