# What is meaning of vlc -I "dummy" "$@"

Tags: scripts, systemd, ubuntu-mate

I understand what exec and vlc do.

But I need help understanding what "-I "dummy" "$@" is doing.

This is related to
[Run script in sleep mode](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1428407/run-script-in-sleep-mode?noredirect=1#comment2488051_1428407)

I have a script in /lib/systemd/system-sleep/ that is not working completely.
It uses cvlc.

```
#! /bin/sh
exec /usr/bin/vlc -I "dummy" "$@"
```

Comment: As explained in `man bash`, `SPECIAL VARIABLES`, `"$@"` is equivalent to "`"$1"` `"$2"` `"$3"` ... ".

Comment: for the meaning of `-I dummy` see `man vlc` and [Documentation:Modules/dummy](https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:Modules/dummy/) from the vlc documentation